# Take form data and write it to XML file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to take form data (via _POST) and write it to a document using SimpleXML. This is what I have tried and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$rss->loadfile("feed.xml");

$item = $rss->channel->addChild('item');
$item->addChild('title', $title);
$item->addChild('link', $link);
$item->addChild('description', $description);

echo $rss->asXML();

header("Location: /success.html"); 

  exit;
?>
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't `echo` something and then use `header()`.

Comment: Always post what error do you get when running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the asXML() function wrong. If you want to write your XML to a file, you must pass a filename parameter to it. Check the [SimpleXMLElement::asXML manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

so your code line oututing xml should be changed from

```
echo $rss->asXML();
```

to

```
$rss->asXML('myNewlyCreatedXML.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than using SimpleXMLElement you can create XML directly like this

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<item>';
$xml .= '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
$xml .= '<link>'.$title.'</link>';
$xml .= '<description>'.$title.'</description>';
$xml .= '</item>';
$xml_file = "feed.xml";
file_put_contents($xml_file,$xml);
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

//$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); // need to have $xmlstr defined before you construct the simpleXML
//$rss->loadfile("feed.xml");
//easier to just load the file when creating your XML object
$rss = new SimpleXML("feed.xml",null,true) // url/path, options, is_url
$item = $rss->channel->addChild('item');
$item->addChild('title', $title);
$item->addChild('link', $link);
$item->addChild('description', $description);


//header("Location: /success.html"); 
//if you want to redirect you should put a timer on it and echo afterwards but by 
//this time if something went wrong there will be output already sent, 
//so you can't send more headers, i.e. the next line will cause an error

header('refresh: 4; URL=/success.html');
echo $rss->asXML(); // you may want to output to a file, rather than the client
// $rss->asXML('outfputfile.xml');
exit;
```

?>

Comment: I am am getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /documentname.php on line 10` error with this. Is it because there is no semicolon on line 9? Because when I put one in I get `Fatal error: Class 'SimpleXML' not found in /documentname.php on line 9`